# How to check whether at least one string of a list of strings is contained in another string?

Tags: mysql, tags, mariadb, substring

I've given a list of tags and a table with a field called `tags`. The tags are stored combined as one string. Before the concatenation, a hashtag is added at the beginning of each tag.

**Example:**

List of tags: `{'summer', 'winter', 'autumn', 'spring'}`

String stored in the table: `'#summer#winter#autumn#spring'`

**Now given a list of tags, how do I query the entries that contain at least one of these given tags in their `tags` string? Is there any specific function or one-line-instruction to achieve this?**

I'm currently fetching all datasets contained in that table, create objects for each of them inside my application and then query these objects based on the given tag list. This is very inconvenient and inefficient as there are around 500.000 datasets in that table. And to always query all of these datasets would take too much time.
An SQL query to receive all the datasets that contain at least one of the given tags could possibly look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE tag_string LIKE '%tag1%' OR tag_string LIKE '%tag2%' OR tag_string LIKE '%tag3%' OR LIKE....
```

But this is inefficient as well, especially for a greater number of given tags.

Can I iterate over each tag and check for a substring with `LOCATE`? Or is there any more efficient way?

I'm working with a MariaDB server version 10.3.21.

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: @etsuhisa It's actually MariaDB, version 10.3.21.

Answer (score 1):

Whist you continue to store data in a "de-normalised" fashion (i.e. the delimited string) you will pay for this in query complexity.

One way to address this problem is to break-up the delimited string into multiple rows, with just one tag in each. Then you can use much simpler and arguably more efficient equality conditions in the where clause. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  , post_body TEXT
  , tags TEXT );

INSERT INTO posts (post_body, tags) 
  VALUES
    ('This is a post about summer.', '#summer#winter#autumn#spring') 
  , ('Some arbitrary fruity but text wintery here.', '#fruit#winter#irrelevant') 
  , ('untagged text here.', NULL) 
  ;
```

then in a recursive CTE generate the extra rows and extract the tag:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 
           id
         , post_body
         , SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags,'#',1) AS tag
         , SUBSTRING(tags, LOCATE('#', tags) + 1) AS rest
         , tags
    FROM posts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
          id
         , post_body
         , SUBSTRING_INDEX(rest,'#',1)
         , SUBSTRING(rest, LOCATE('#', rest) + 1)
         , tags
    FROM cte
    WHERE LOCATE('#', rest) > 0
)
SELECT id, post_body, tag, tags
FROM cte
WHERE tag IN('summer','winter')
ORDER BY id, tag;
```

**Result** (from sample):

```
id  post_body                                       tag     tags
1   This is a post about summer.                    summer  #summer#winter#autumn#spring
1   This is a post about summer.                    winter  #summer#winter#autumn#spring
2   Some arbitrary fruity but text wintery here.    winter  #fruit#winter#irrelevant
```

see: https://dbfiddle.uk/QPhgV2O6

Note: `WHERE tag IN('summer','winter')` is the equivalent of `(tag = 'summer' or tag = 'winter')` and you **avoid** the need for wildcards and `LIKE`

---

Another way is to treat the current tags data as if they are JSON, this then allows use of `JSON_SEARCH` (nb the "one" you see in these it to match to lust 1 element of the JSON)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT post_body,
         CONCAT('["', REPLACE(TRIM(LEADING '#' FROM tags), '#', '","'), '"]') AS tags_json
  FROM posts
) AS subq
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(tags_json, 'one', 'summer') IS NOT NULL 
   OR JSON_SEARCH(tags_json, 'one', 'winter') IS NOT NULL;
```

Or use JSON to store the tags, here I add another column `json_tag` (type longtext) for the example:

```
UPDATE posts
SET json_tags = CONCAT('["', REPLACE(TRIM(LEADING '#' FROM tags), '#', '","'), '"]');
```

Now it is possible to use `JSON_SEARCH` like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(json_tags, 'one', 'summer') IS NOT NULL 
   OR JSON_SEARCH(json_tags, 'one', 'winter') IS NOT NULL;
```

See this variant: https://dbfiddle.uk/H7fGkHFH

nb: I do not know how well this would perform on your data, nor how difficult it would be to use JSON instead of what you do now.